# Find MD5 hash of files inside a tar.gz file in java without extracting it

Tags: java, apache-spark, md5, tar.gz

I have a huge tar.gz file with lots of images in it. I need to find the md5 hash of each images. I am not able to find hash of images inside the tar file but same code works for normal folders and images. Is there any way to find hash without extracting the tar?

```
public static String digestAndBuildImageEntry(Path filePath) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
            try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(filePath);
                    BufferedInputStream buffered = new BufferedInputStream(is)) {

                byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(filePath);
                byte[] hashByte = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(data);

                String hash = hashByte.toString();
                return hash;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

**I get below exception when i run this code**

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /Users/myuser/old/file.tar.gz/1.jpg: Not a directory
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:144)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1737)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.getAttributes(FileTreeWalker.java:219)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:276)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:322)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.<init>(FileTreeIterator.java:72)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walk(Files.java:3574)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walk(Files.java:3625)
    at com.example.demo.ImageDeduplication.listFiles(ImageDeduplication.java:78)
    at com.example.demo.SparkSQL.lambda$1(SparkSQL.java:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration.$anonfun$register$352(UDFRegistration.scala:775)
    ... 17 more
```

Below Path variables worked

- /Users/myuser/old/1.jpg - worked
- /Users/myuser/old/ - able to iterate and get all file inside the folder
- /Users/myuser/old/file.tar.gz - gives the hash of the entire tar file

Not working for

- /Users/myuser/old/file.tar.gz/1.jpg -  says not a directory

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "extracting". You *can* read the content without writing it to disk, but you *can not* read the content without interpreting the tar. And since `tar` (especially when compressed with `.gz`) is not searchable, you will have to read the whole archive until you get to your desired file to read it.

Comment: I need to find the md5 hash of all the images inside the tar.gz to find if it has duplicates. I have the name of the image files with me. I was thinking to use Spark to process and find the md5 for all images inside. Now i guess if i use Spark, then each thread will try to access the tar.gz stream

Comment: If you need the SHA for each file in there, then you can do that in a single go through. You'll still need to read/decompress the whole file, but can do so efficiently (i.e. without holding even a whole file in memory at one time, fully streaming with small buffers).

Comment: Got it. Issue is with the tar.gz format which doesnt allow random access. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Commons Compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/index.html) has classes that can stream `tar.gz` format.
From [examples](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/examples.html#tar) and [docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/tar.html) it would be something like this:

```java
try (InputStream fi = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("my.tar.gz"));
     InputStream bi = new BufferedInputStream(fi);
     InputStream gzi = new GzipCompressorInputStream(bi);
     TarArchiveInputStream tarInput = new TarArchiveInputStream(gzi)) {
    TarArchiveEntry entry = tarInput.getNextTarEntry();
    
    // here you can read specific file's content and do md5 computation
    byte[] content = new byte[entry.getSize()];
    tarInput.read(content, offset, content.length - offset);
}
```

Another option to quickly access files inside of tar.gz is to mount it as virtual file system by [commons-vfs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/filesystems.html)

Comment: I have the file name inside the tar.gz. Should i iterate all the TarArchiveEntry to find the specific file? Is it possible to access the file directly and get md5 hash?

Comment: @Anonymous You can also take a look at commons-vfs - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs

Comment: Apache Common Compress worked as you suggested. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of common compress has TarFile class which provides random access to the files and inputstream. We can get the TarArchiveEntry of each files as a list and get the corresponding inputstream from the exposed method in TarFile class. Below code worked for me.

```
public  static Map<String,String> getMD5HashMap(String path) throws Exception {
         Map<String,String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
         FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
         GzipCompressorInputStream gzIn = new GzipCompressorInputStream(in);
         byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(gzIn);
        
        TarFile tarFile = new TarFile(bytes);
        for(TarArchiveEntry tarArchiveEntry:tarFile.getEntries()) {
            
            if(tarArchiveEntry.isFile()) {
                try(InputStream is = tarFile.getInputStream(tarArchiveEntry);
                        BufferedInputStream buffered = new BufferedInputStream(is)){
                    
                    String hash = DigestUtils.md5Hex(buffered);
                    map.put(tarArchiveEntry.getName(), hash);
                    System.out.println(hash);
                }
            }
            
        }
        return map;
    
    }
```